# iTerm2でビープ音を消す方法

Tags: macos, iterm

完全にビープ音を鳴らさず、またVisual Beepも行わない設定にしたく

#### ~/.inputrc

```
set bell-style none
```

と設定して iTerm2の Preferences->Profile->Terminal->Notification の`Silence bell`のチェックを入れて iTermを再起動したのですが、Tabにて補完する際に候補が複数あると毎回ビープ音がなってしまいます。

どうすればビープ音をならないように出来るでしょうか？

環境は OSX 10.9.5 になります。

Comment: Silence bellのチェックでビープ音は鳴らなくなります。少なくとも僕の環境ではそうやって止めてあります。設定を変更したProfile名と実際に使っているProfileは一致していますか？

Comment: ご指摘の通り、別プロファイルを作っているのに出Defaultの部分を変更してしまっていました。ありがとうございます。